# Merb authentication question, _message variable

Tags: ruby, merb, merb-auth

Im using merb, and getting weird variable in url after authentication. I figured out that variable contains base64 encoded data, but cannot understand why its appearing there, even if everything works ok. Just curious

It looks like this: http://foo.bar/?_message=....data....
What this variable for and what does it do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

_message is the way that Merb sends 'flash' messages. I believe that it is being encoded to make it harder to spoof (i.e. insert arbitrary text on your Web page) but to keep the state in the URL

Comment: You might find this google groups post helpful

http://groups.google.com/group/merb/browse_thread/thread/bf3d66ba709ce7e3/3437599852131d3a?lnk=raot